# Regex and creating output file (Perl beginner)

Tags: regex, perl

I'm in an intro to Perl course and we are tasked with taking an input.txt file (of the Gettysburg Address - that has all instances of the word 'old' changed to 'new') and creating an output.txt file that switches 'new' back to having 'old'. I've got a general regex that switches all instances of 'new' to 'old', but it needs to work regardless of case in the input file. I'm wondering how I could add that in? Also, I'm looking to verify that I have my output.txt built in correctly? When I run what I have, I get no output.txt file created in my directory. Here is what I have so far:

```
open(my $getty, "<", "input.txt")
    or die "Cannot open < input.txt: $!";

open(my $getty, ">", "output.txt")
    or die "Cannot open < output.txt: $!";

while(my $line = <$getty>) {
    if ($line =~ 's/new/old/') {
        $line =~ s/new/old/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Always `use strict;` ... you are trying to use the `$getty` Filehandle twice (one for reading and one for writing). The `use strict;` would have warned you.

Comment: I will add `use strict;`. So I need to create a new Filehandle for my open output - (understood). How can I write everything from my input.txt to my output.txt with the switch from 'new' to 'old' made? Also, I want to assume output.txt does not exist at time the code executes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put an if condition.

```
while(my $line = <$getty>) {
    $line =~ s/new/old/gi;
}
```

Comment: OP includes condition `needs to work regardless of case in the input file`. This may mean NEW -> OLD  and nEw -> oLd, new -> old, etc. If replacement's case is not important, i-switch is enough.

Comment: How do I get this to write to output.txt, which at time of execution does not exist?

Comment: open it. Print to it.

Comment: @w.k then add an `i` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The good recipe is to change smth. from shell by Perl:

```
perl -pi.orig -e 's{old}{new}g' filename.txt
```

This produce replacement in file filename.txt wtih an original file filename.txt.orig

Comment: I think yo mean -pi.orig , to that the output will be written to the file.

Comment: Conceptually correct, my typing was unforgivable :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your course is over, however here is a complete answer for anyone who might need it:
The `if` is unnecessary. You need to use `print` on the output filehandle to create the file. Here is the complete working code (there is no comma after the filehandle in the print statement):

```
use strict;

open(my $in_file, "<", "input.txt")
    or die "Cannot open < input.txt: $!";

open(my $out_file, ">", "output.txt")
    or die "Cannot open < output.txt: $!";

while(my $line = <$in_file>) {
    $line =~ s/new/old/i;
    print $out_file $line;
}
```

If the case of the input word should be the same in the output word, this is a solution:

```
use strict;

open(my $in_file, "<", "input.txt")
    or die "Cannot open < input.txt: $!";

open(my $out_file, ">", "output.txt")
    or die "Cannot open < output.txt: $!";

while(my $line = <$in_file>) {
    $line =~ s{(new)}
    {
        my @chars = split '', $1;
        my @old = qw/o l d/;
        my @out;
        foreach my $char (@chars) {
            if($char =~ /\p{Uppercase}/) {
                push @out, uc(shift @old);
            }
            else {
                push @out, shift @old;
            }
        }
        join('', @out);
    }esi;
    print $out_file $line;
 }
```

What happens here is that I use `s{pattern}{replacement}`. The `e` modifier makes the replacement part perl code and `s` makes it possible for me to use whitespace in the expression. In the replecement code I go trough every char of the "new" (captured with braces so I can check it in the variable `$1`). If the char is uppercase I use the `uc` function to make the output char uppercase aswell.